# How to close a hidden window (WPF application)?

Tags: c#, wpf, window

In my application (WPF) i have this window:

`public partial class Window1 : Window` and in the Xaml `x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"`

Now, when i switch to and from the main to window 1 and back, i us the Visibility.Hidden and Visibility.Visible to hide them and make them show again to the user.

What i try to do now, is make a test button in the main window, that says: Close Window1.
This window is hidden, but i really want to close it in the background.
at first i though to just use the `Window.Close();` but that does not seem to do the trick.

So, how should i do this in a correct way ?
Thank you very much in advance.

***EDIT 1 - making question more clear***

To open the window1 in my Main window, i use this part

```
Window1 W1 = null; // Initialise Field.
  public void CalcTabel_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
    if (W1 == null)
    {
     W1 = new Window1();
     W1.Hoofdmenu = this;
     W1.checkLang();
     W1.Show();
    }
   else
    {
     W1.checkLang();
     W1.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
   this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
   }
```

On window 1 there is a Back button, that has this snip-it of code in it (Where "Hoofdmenu" us the main window):

```
Hoofdmenu.updateStatistics();
Hoofdmenu.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
this.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
```

But again, this time **when standing in the main window (so window 1 is hidden)** i want to close down that window 1. but using `W1.Close()` does not seem to work. So i am looking for a way to Close that window 1, **not** change its visibility.

***EDIT 2 - Solution***

So using `W1.Close();` did **not** work, although a small change `this.W1.Close();` did work in fact :)

Comment: Why are you shure the hidden window is not closing? Could you post more of the sample code to clarify what you're doing? Anything done on closing that breaks the close signal?

Comment: Within window1, some buttons have been clicked, changing the look of it. I can be sure that the window has not been closed for real, because else they would have been reset to default, and that did not happen. I'll see if i can edit the above some more to make it i bit more clear.

Comment: Could you put W1.Close() in Try Catch block and post the exception?

Comment: posted the solution in my edit :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create object of Form2 in window and intialize its visiblity to false.

On click of button you can simpliy say

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
    private Window1 window2;

    public MainWindow()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.window2 = new Window1();

      this.window2.Show();
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      this.window2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
    }
  }
```

to make it visible again

Comment: edited your post, and clearing come comments here for future readability :)

Answer (score 0):

after reading your code, thats not possible the way you want it. the window1 instance is local object. so you cant reach it out side if this method.
the best was is to have a close button on window1 with this.close()
or you create a global instance in your main window and then check if not null then close it.